# Почему смещена точка прикосновения курсора с линией?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse-event, mousemove

Пробую кастомизировать проект на Codepen. Столкнулся с тем, что когда сanvas занимает не весь экран, а находится после **элемента** с произвольной высотой - событие mousemove смещается на высоту этого **элемента**.

Само событие я вешаю непосредственно на контейнер в котором находится холст.

Предполагаю, что проблема в этом коде, но к сожалению не могу разобраться

Код:

```js
if ((mouseDirectionX > 0 && mouseX > this.x) || (mouseDirectionX < 0 && mouseX < this.x)) {
    if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx) < vars.mouseDist && Math.sqrt(dy * dy) < gap) {
      this.vx = mouseSpeedX / 8
    }
  }
```

Оригинальный Codepen: [click](https://codepen.io/waaark/pen/ENRvvq)
Мой Codepen: [click](https://codepen.io/levais/pen/agyJgz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в другом месте, используйте вместо `pageX` и `pageY` `layerX` и `layerY`

```html
<div class="stub"></div>

<section id="container">
  <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
</section>

<div class="stub"></div>

<style>
body {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.stub {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: salmon;
}
</style>

<script>
let points = [];
let rafID = null;
let container = document.getElementById("container");

let sett = {
  totalPoints: 12,
  viscosity: 20,
  mouseDist: 120,
  damping: 0.15,
  showIndicators: true,
  bgColor: "#f4f3f8",
  accentColor: "#e3dfeb"
};

let mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0,
  mouseLastX = 0,
  mouseLastY = 0,
  mouseDirectionX = 0,
  mouseDirectionY = 0,
  mouseSpeedX = 0,
  mouseSpeedY = 0;

function mouseDirection(e) {
  if (mouseX < e.layerX)
    mouseDirectionX = 1;
  else if (mouseX > e.layerX)
    mouseDirectionX = -1;
  else
    mouseDirectionX = 0;

  if (mouseY < e.layerY)
    mouseDirectionY = 1;
  else if (mouseY > e.layerY)
    mouseDirectionY = -1;
  else
    mouseDirectionY = 0;

  mouseX = e.layerX;
  mouseY = e.layerY;
}

container.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseDirection, {
  passive: true
});

function mouseSpeed() {
  mouseSpeedX = mouseX - mouseLastX;
  mouseSpeedY = mouseY - mouseLastY;

  mouseLastX = mouseX;
  mouseLastY = mouseY;

  setTimeout(mouseSpeed, 50);
}

mouseSpeed();

function Point(x, y, canvas) {
  this.y = y;
  this.iy = y;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.cy = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.ix = x;
  this.cx = 0;
  this.canvas = canvas;
}

Point.prototype.move = function() {
  this.vy += (this.iy - this.y) / sett.viscosity;

  let dy = this.iy - mouseY,
    dx = this.x - mouseX;

  let gap = this.canvas.gap;

  // Move point only when leaving color block
  if ((mouseDirectionY > 0 && mouseY > this.y) || (mouseDirectionY < 0 && mouseY < this.y)) {
    if (Math.sqrt(dy * dy) < sett.mouseDist && Math.sqrt(dx * dx) < gap) {
      this.vy = mouseSpeedY / 8;
    }
  }

  this.vy *= (1 - sett.damping);
  this.y += this.vy;
};

function initCanvas() {
  let canvas = container.querySelector(".canvas");
  cancelAnimationFrame(rafID);

  // Resize canvas
  canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;

  // Add points
  points = [];
  let totalPointsHalf = sett.totalPoints / 2;
  let height = canvas.height;
  let width = canvas.width;
  let gap = width / (totalPointsHalf - 1);
  let pointX; // Координата на оси Х
  let pointY; // Координата на оси Y

  for (let i = totalPointsHalf - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    pointX = i * gap;
    pointY = height / 2.5;

    points.push(new Point(pointX, pointY, canvas));
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= totalPointsHalf - 1; i++) {
    pointX = i * gap;
    pointY = height / 1.5;

    points.push(new Point(pointX, pointY, canvas));
  }

  // Start render
  renderCanvas();

  canvas.gap = gap;
}

function renderCanvas() {
  let canvas = container.querySelector(".canvas");
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let width = canvas.width;
  let height = canvas.height;

  // rAF
  rafID = requestAnimationFrame(renderCanvas);

  // Clear scene
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.fillStyle = sett.bgColor;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  // Move points
  for (let i = 0; i <= sett.totalPoints - 1; i++)
    points[i].move();

  // Draw shape
  context.fillStyle = sett.accentColor;
  context.strokeStyle = sett.accentColor;
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.beginPath();

  context.moveTo(width, height / 2.5);

  for (let i = 0; i <= sett.totalPoints - 1; i++) {
    let p = points[i];

    if (points[i + 1] != undefined) {
      // - 0.0001 hack to fix a 1px offset bug on Chrome...
      p.cy = (p.y + points[i + 1].y) / 2 - 0.0001; 
      p.cx = (p.x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
    } else {
      p.cy = p.iy;
      p.cx = p.ix;
    }

    if (i === (sett.totalPoints / 2 - 1)) {
      context.bezierCurveTo(0, p.y, 0, height / 2.5, 0, height / 2.5);
    } else if (i === (sett.totalPoints / 2)) {
      context.lineTo(0, height / 1.5);
    } else {
      context.bezierCurveTo(p.x, p.y, p.cx, p.cy, p.cx, p.cy);
    }
  }

  context.closePath();
  context.fill();

  if (sett.showIndicators) {
    // Draw points
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.beginPath();
    for (let i = 0; i <= sett.totalPoints - 1; i++) {
      let p = points[i];

      context.rect(p.x - 2, p.y - 2, 4, 4);
    }
    context.fill();

    // Draw controls
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.beginPath();
    for (let i = 0; i <= sett.totalPoints - 1; i++) {
      let p = points[i];

      context.rect(p.cx - 1, p.cy - 1, 2, 2);
    }
    context.fill();
  }
}

function resizeHandler() {
  initCanvas();
}

resizeHandler();

window.onresize = resizeHandler;
</script>
```